# python 3.x - text based adventure game, save game function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a text based adventure game. I am about half way done and before I get much farther with the story line I want to implement a save game function. I've been trying to figure it out all afternoon but I can't seem to find any indication of how to do it right, for my scenario anyways.

Here is a decent portion of the code, I have more that I didn't paste here but it's just story pacing basically. What I want to be able to do is have a choice ie. 5 = save game which saves players1 statistics and when loaded puts the player back in the same spot in the game /w s`enter code here`

I can't get the code to paste in here due to length I believe so I have a pastebin link.

http://pastebin.com/gJPa2TEe

Any help is much appreciated, I'm trying to learn programming.

Comment: Heads up, this may be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606097/python-text-game-how-to-make-a-save-feature)

Comment: @kensai01 Take a look at that link ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have some things that define state like : self.__player_health, self.__player_name, self.__health_potion, self.__big_wrench, self.__blue_keycard. I need to read more carefully, but couldn't find a state that defines progression. With everything that defines the state you can save and read from a text file - if you are aiming at simplicity.

One way to go would be having a dict structure to store text, time to wait and function (if available, like the fighting ), like pages. Then using an array to store these pages, which would be your book. If you have a loop to keep reading those pages - reading would be another function. Then since the story is indexed, you now know where you are, so just save the states and position.

Unrelated : just use import at the top instead of every time.

edit:

```
import sys, traceback
import json

userQuited = False

def _quit(dummy):
    global userQuited
    userQuited = True

def _save(dummy):
    f=open("game.sav",'w+')
    json.dump(states, f)
    f.close

def _continue(dummy):
    f=open("game.sav",'r+')   
    states = json.load(f)
    f.close

def user(name):
    states["player_name"] = name

states = {
    "player_health" : 100,
    "player_name" : "",
    "health_potion" : 0,
    "big_wrench" : 0,
    "blue_keycard" : 0,
    "current_page" : "page1"
}

book = { 
    "page1": {
        "text": """You are in an underwater research facility that has been
attacked by unknown assailants. As the assistant to the head
researcher, you were hired in to assist Dr. Weathers with
the Lightning Sword project. Project Lightning Sword still
remains in large a mystery to you. Although you worked closely
with the doctor you were never allowed to see the big picture.
Right now that's the least of your worries, as chaos ensues around you.
Alarms were triggered a while ago. As you sit in your room,
you hear short bursts of automatic rifle fire and only one
thing is for certain, you have to survive.\n """,
        "inputText": "What would you like your player to be named?",
        "function": user,
        "next": "page2"
    },
    "page2": {
        "text": "Welcome, %(player_name)s please choose what you would like to do",
        "inputText": "0 = Quit, 1 = Start New Game, 2 = Continue",
        "choices": {
            "0" : "Quit",
            "1" : "page3",
            "2" : "Continue"
        }
    },
    "page3" : {
        "text" : """You are standing in your room, door is locked and you're wondering
if you will get out of this alive. The gunfire keeps getting closer and you know that you
can't stay here, you have to make a move and try and get out. Otherwise it's just a matter
of time before they find you and that option doesn't look very promising.\n\n

You are ready to try your escape but first you should try and get any useful
things from your room to use along the way. Your room-office is a bit bigger than a walk in closet,
textile flooring and gray walls encompas your view and the only things in the room are the bed you
are sitting on (not very comfortable, looks more like a prisoners bed), a framed picture on the wall
and your work desk which has barely enough space for your equipment and computer.""",
        "inputText": "1 = Walk over to the picture frame, 2 = Walk over to the desk, 3 = Exit the door",
        "choices": {
            "1" : "page4",
            "2" : "page5",
            "3" : "page7"
        }
    },

    "Quit" : {
        "text": "goodbye!",
        "inputText": "",
        "function" : _quit
    },
    "Continue" : {
        "text": "welcome back!",
        "inputText": "",
        "function" : _continue
    }
}



def processPage(page):
    answer = ""
    print(page["text"] % states)
    if len(page["inputText"]) > 1 :
        answer = raw_input(page["inputText"] % states)
    if "function" in page:
        page["function"](answer)
    if "next" in page:
        return page["next"]
    if "choices" in page:
        for choice in page["choices"]:
            if choice == answer:
                print page["choices"][choice]
                return page["choices"][choice]
    return ""

def main():
    global userQuited
    while(userQuited==False):
        states["current_page"] = processPage(book[states["current_page"] ])
        if (states["current_page"] != "Quit" and states["current_page"] != "Continue"):
            _save("")

main()
```

So a lot of your code is repeating... I'm trying to keep it in a pattern. The idea here is a loop to print and navigate in your story. For each iteration, the current_page is saved  with other states. By using continue the game is loaded from the file.

The rest is a small text game engine I made based on your code pattern. Modify and create on top of it.

Comment: Yes save/read from a text file is what I am aiming to do exactly. The simpler the better, I have to be able to understand/be able to explain the code.
I understand what you mean about indexing the progression of the story from an abstract point of view; however I can't figure out how to turn the newbie mess of code into something that can be indexed. I feel like I coded and coded but I didn't account for the

Comment: Did you understand the book page analogy? I did thinking in the old adventure books but I don't know if you got it...

Comment: First use raw_input instead of input. Is this homework?

Comment: I thought raw_input isn't used in 3.x + of python.

Comment: sorry, I'm using python 2.7, didn't knew. Ok, I've submitted an idea - you need to understand and build on top of it... will try to come with an explanation of the code..

Comment: Looks great, I've been tinkering with the code now trying to understand what things do and how it works for a minute now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok, you need to fill the remaining pages - I think there are a lot of them, but do page by page, test it, understand the results. Lots of things can break in the process, so take your time.

Comment: answer = input(page["inputText"] % states) < what does that % states do at the end?

Comment: right, this is a cheat I'm using! use ctrl+f to find %(player_name)s . Found it? so, % in the string is a special character, it will look for whatever between parenthesis later in a dict structure, and display as string (the 's' after the parenthesis). Where will it look? Well, the % symbol after tell where to look, and the dict is states. More info here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: Btw, if you like my answer, please vote it up or mark as 'the answer'

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SBpSjCGu

I added comments throughout your code following the flow and explaining it (to myself mostly). I have written out a few questions throughout as I encountered things I couldn't explain to myself. Can you look it over/let me know if my thinking is right + explain a few details of the code you wrote that are unclear to me.

Comment: Here are some answers: http://pastebin.com/zmbYMK9U  . I've been thinking about this, if this is like your first big dive in Python, this may be a little too much - so the simpler approach you were doing would be better, just the save is a problem. In other languages there is something called goto that enables going to a specified line of the code - Python doesn't have because using it  in high level languages is considered bad practice, but it would be exactly what you needed in the first place...

Comment: Hey Elric. I have pretty much finished most of my code, I have to polish it now. Can you look at it for me? I'm getting traceback errors with KeyError: None after running certain functions. Basically it's not taking the new current page after the function to the main. I add a return statement to fix one but then another breaks. I keep fixing them one by one by adding return statements but another just breaks with the same error, sometimes some that already have return statements. I'm thinking that I have a fundamental flaw somewhere that I'm not seeing.

http://pastebin.com/VkEYXQSH < code

Comment: First, don't use sys.exit(0), use _quit(0) and set next to "Quit".
Found. The Wrench page has no "next" and no "choices" defined, so when it gets to it, the processPage function does not return anything. Then, at the next iteration the loop will go to the next page, but since states["current_page"] is empty (look in the loop, it will set it!) it won't go to a next page. If you want your function to give where to go, an alternative would be update the loop to it: http://pastebin.com/AxLSfQdW

Comment: I see you use main() in similar fashion to goto (c) or jp (assembly), is your background in micro-controllers?

Comment: No I have been programming for 4 weeks, first class I've taken so far.