# Python Getting Level Settings

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I am in the process of making a text based game in python and I am having some trouble in making the save game feature. I found this page; [Python text game: how to make a save feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606097/python-text-game-how-to-make-a-save-feature) and I put those features in, but I am unsure of how to get it to go to the level the player last went on.

Example:

```
# saving the file
with open('savefile.dat', 'wb') as f:
pickle.dump([player, level_state], f, protocol=2)

# loading the file
with open('savefile.dat', 'rb') as f:
player, level_state = pickle.load(f)
```

The `level_state` variable tells the code what level the player was on, but how do I get it to go to that level?

Sorry - I'm a noob at this. The game starts with a short introduction and then asks for a new or loaded game.

```
load = input('New game or load game?\n')
if load in ('new','new game'):
    print('You have started a new game.')
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Don't forget to save before you quit.")
    time.sleep(2)
    level1() #this starts the game from the beginning
elif load in ('load','load game'):
    loadname = input('What is your name?\n')
    with open('%s_game.dat' % loadname, 'rb') as f:
        name, level = pickle.load(f)
```

After it loads the game, I want the code to resume on the level that was saved in the file. For example, do level1() or level2().

Comment: The `player` and `level_state` variables in the linked question are just examples to illustrate how to save and recover two variables.  Implementing a save mechanism is up to you and depends entirely on the details of your game and how it carries its state.

Comment: The `player` and `level_state` variable I have changed for my game - the example I put in was how the variable was changed. I just need a way of making the variable go to the saved level.

Comment: I can't possibly tell you how to do that, since you haven't told me anything about your game!  What is a "level"?  How is it defined and used in your code?  You can't expect an answer when the question lacks any of the detail that would be required to answer it.

Comment: In the linked question that you gave I liked the answer which began "First, don't overthink this". I suggest taking that answer to heart before you worry about how to use the pickle module (which could very well be overkill for a simple text game).

Comment: Maybe I should leave this for now... thanks for your help.

Comment: When you find yourself numbering your variables, like `level1`, `level2`, etc., you may need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you'd need, however the most generic thing you could do is to use `dill.dump_session` and `dill.load_session`, to dump and load your entire python session to a file, and then restart it with all the objects you have live.  Essentially, whenever you finish (or start?) a level, you could save the entire session to a file… and then if you want to restart there, just load the file with `dill.load_session.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 25 2015, 13:16:30) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import dill
>>> 
>>> squared = lambda x:x**2
>>> import numpy
>>> x = numpy.arange(10)
>>> dill.dump_session('level1.pkl')
>>>
```

Then, quit and restart...

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 25 2015, 13:16:30) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> dill.load_session('level1.pkl')
>>> y = squared(x)
>>> y
array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81])
```